# Function "ets" from package "forecast": How long is the season?

Tags: r, forecasting

The letter "s" in the name of the function `ets` from the "forecast" package stands for "season", as explained [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/7). But among the arguments of the `ets`-function that are listed in the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/ets) I can't find the *length* of the season.  So how long is the season?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the data. Monthly data has seasons of length 12, Quarterly data has seasons of length 4, and so on. Further examples are provided at http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/

Comment: This means that the length of the season is undefined if `ets` is applied to a numeric vector without timestamps. And if there are timestamps, the length of the season can only be one year.

Comment: The season length is set to 1 if the first argument is not a ts object.

Comment: The documentation doesn't tell anything about this. And a season of length 1 doesn't really  make sense. It is quasi nonseasonal. I apply for an optional argument to choose the season length.